# Circuit diagram of the Full Order Observer

Tags: circuit-design, control-system

I am a novice in the field of control system and electronics *per se*.

I am trying to implement the **Full-order observer** in an electrical circuit made of R, C and Op-amps.

I understand the **block diagram**, but I am unsure of how the circuit will look like.

The **block diagram** is as follows:

[image]

**r** is a voltage signal.

Any kind of help will be useful.

**N.B.** As I am at the early phase of learning, providing links to resources while you answer the question will be a big help.

Thank you.

Comment: What is a full order observer?

Comment: @Andyaka Have a look at this [tutorial](https://www.eolss.net/Sample-Chapters/C18/E6-43-13-08.pdf)